# How to access to nested object style in react-jss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I want to access this nested object in React JSS 
I am using injectSheet from React-JSS

```js
export const textStyle = {
  size: {
    '&:larger': {
       fontSize: '1.28em'
    },
    '&:large': {
      fontSize: '1.250em'
    }
}
```

I am accessing in `className={this.props.classes.size.larger}`
but getting the undefined value or error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such pseudo selector in css :larger, you are doing something wrong.